# Resizing 2D Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, multidimensional-array

currently I am trying to resize a 2D Array in C using this code snippet

```
array = (int**) realloc(array, s * 2 * sizeof(int));
```

Where s is the size of the array in rows and colums. However, when trying to access the new areas of the array like this,

```
array[3][0] = x;
```

I only get a segfault. The old areas of the array work fine. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: are you _sure_ that `array` is an _array_?

Comment: **Pointers are not arrays**. Pointer to pointer doesn't mean array of arrays.

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How did you declare `array` and how did you initially allocate it?

Comment: Assuming that you declared `array` correctly and that you fixed every warning from your compiler there is a fundamental mistake using `realloc()`. These functions all, return `NULL` on failure, in that case you loose reference to the orignal pointer causing a memory leak. Use a temporary variable, and depending on the value of `s` you might be asking for an unavailable ammount of memory, so check that `arary` is not `NULL` before `array[3][0] = x`, last but not least don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: See section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: For resizable "2D arrays" (an array of pointers, like you declare, which each point to their own row, which are allocated 1D arrays), you'll typically need the allocation you show for the pointers, and then an iteration over the pointers in order to allocate the row each pointer is to point to. Right now you only have a 1D array of pointers (the `int **` not withstanding).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you declared `array` as

```
int **array;
```

and allocated as

```
array = malloc( sizeof *array * ROWS );
if ( array )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ )
    array[i] = malloc( sizeof *array[i] * COLS );
}
```

The structure you wind up with looks something like:

```
       +---+        +---+                  +---+
array: |   | -----> |   | array[0] ------> |   | array[0][0]
       +---+        +---+                  +---+
        ...         |   | array[1] ---+    |   | array[0][1]
                    +---+             |    +---+
                     ...              |    |   | array[0][2]
                                      |    +---+
                                      |     ...
                                      |    
                                      |    +---+
                                      +--> |   | array[1][0]
                                           +---+
                                           |   | array[1][1]
                                           +---+
                                           |   | array[1][2]
                                           +---+
                                            ...
```

If you want to increase the number of *rows* in the array but leave the column sizes the same, you'd do something like

```
int **tmp = realloc( array, sizeof *array * (ROWS + add_rows) );
if ( tmp )
{
  array = tmp;
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < add_rows; i++ )
  {
     array[ROWS + i] = malloc( sizeof *array[ROWS + i] * COLS );
  }
}
```

If you want to leave the number of rows the same but increase the number of *columns* in each row, you would do something like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ )
{
  int *tmp = realloc( array[i], sizeof *array[i] * (COLS + add_cols) );
  if ( tmp )
  {
    array[i] = tmp;
  }
}
```

If you want to *reduce* the number of rows in the array, you will need to free the affected rows first:

```
for ( size_t i = 1; i <= del_rows; i++ )
  free( array[ROWS - i] );

int *tmp = realloc( array, ROWS - del_rows );
if ( tmp )
  array = tmp;
```

If you want to reduce the number of columns:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < ROWS: i++ )
{
  int *tmp = realloc( array[i], sizeof *array[i] * (COLS - del_cols) );
  if ( tmp )
    array[i] = tmp;
}
```

From there, you should be able to figure out any combinations you need.  I *strongly* recommend doing only one dimension at a time (that is, if you want to increase the number of rows *and* columns, do the rows *first*, then do the columns).

You *always* want to assign the result of `realloc` to a temporary variable; if `realloc` cannot satisfy the request, it will return `NULL`, and if you assign it back to the original variable, you will lose your only reference to the memory that was previously allocated, leading to a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a function to resize a 2D array in C:

```
int** ResizeGrid(int** A, uint64_t rows, uint64_t cols, uint64_t newRow, uint64_t newCol)
{
  // If old size is same as new size, return the same grid
  // if (newRow == rows && newCol == cols) {
  //   return A;
  // }

  // If new size is smaller than old size, free the extra memory
  if (rows > newRow) {
    for (uint64_t i = newRow; i < rows; i++) {
      free(A[i]);
    }
    return A;
  }

  A = (int**)realloc(A, sizeof(int*) * newRow);
  // Check if realloc fails
  if (A == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  for (uint64_t i = 0; i < newRow; i++) {
    // Reallocate memory only on already allocated rows
    if (rows > i) {
      A[i] = (int*)realloc(A[i], sizeof(int) * newCol);
    } else {
      A[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * newCol);
    }
    // Check if realloc/malloc fails
    if (A[i] == NULL) {
      // Free all the rows that have been allocated
      for (uint64_t j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        free(A[j]);
      }
      free(A);

      return NULL;
    }
  }
  return A;
}
```

An [example implementation of the function](https://github.com/bensuperpc/game-of-life/blob/48ae9a1df4f5a8c8932eae9c1b549db3468bf78c/source/lib/source/gol.c#L35)