# How to grow array of character arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, char, malloc

I am trying to grow the following array of character arrays:

```
char  input_channel_name[ 20 ][ 36 ];
```

The number of columns will always be 36, but the number of rows can vary.  When I open my file, I can grab the number of channel names as an integer `number_of_channels_in`

I have tried to convert it to the follow code (with help of [Resizing 2D Arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208929/resizing-2d-arrays-in-c)) without luck:

```
#define  ROWS 20
#define  COLS 36

main( argc, argv )
    char **input_channel_name;

    input_channel_name = malloc(sizeof *input_channel_name * ROWS);
        if ( input_channel_name )
        {
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ )
                input_channel_name[i] = malloc( sizeof *input_channel_name[i] * COLS);
        }

get_input_channels:
    input_file = fopen( input_name, "rb" )
    fread( plotFileHeader.headerFloats, sizeof( float ), 2, input_file );
    number_of_channels_in = plotFileHeader.headerFloats[ N_CHAN_SUB ];
    add_rows = number_of_channels_in - ROWS;

    char **tmp = realloc( input_channel_name, sizeof *input_channel_name * ROWS + add_rows);
    if ( tmp )
    {
        input_channel_name = tmp;
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < add_rows; i++ )
        {
            input_channel_name[ROWS + i] = malloc( sizeof *input_channel_name[ROWS + i] * COLS);
        }
    }
```

I keep getting an

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

when I try to set `input_channel_name = malloc`

Any ideas?

Comment: Please take the time to make your program a proper [mcve]. Prototype main as required, add missing include directives, etc.

Comment: `main( argc, argv )` --> `int main( int argc, char **argv ){ ... }`

Comment: That's not an "array of `char` arrays", but an pointer to pointer. Completely different datatypes.

Comment: I apologize, C is my kryptonite and I am working with a project that is over 10,000 lines of code.  I am just trying to update the arrays such that I can allocate memory during run-time.  I thought it would be a quick fix, but it turns out that is not the case.  I will work on slimming my code down, but I don't know how to build a complete and verifiable example when it doesn't compile in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your programs downfall is that it treats arrays as pointers. They are in fact not one and the same, and you can't us a `char**` to a access a true mult-dimensional array directly.

The way to declare a pointer to an array of 36 characters is as follows:

```
char (*p_arr)[36] = NULL;
```

To have it point to the first such array in a `malloc`-ed block you'd proceed normally:

```
char (*p_arr)[36] = malloc(row_count * sizeof *p_arr);
```

Or, if you're the typedefing sort:

```
typedef char c_arr_36[36];
c_arr_36 *p_arr = malloc(row_count * sizeof(c_arr_36));
```

Comment: I will try to digest this and make sense of it.  Out of curiousity, is the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208929/resizing-2d-arrays-in-c incorrect?  It appeared to be the most straightforward answer I could find and pretty much used it line for line.

Also, in your example, what exactly is the variable for the array?  Isn't *p_arr a pointer?  Isn't that what I was trying to avoid?

Comment: @Das.Rot - The answer is not incorrect, but it doesn't deal with true multi-dimensional arrays, which is what you were trying to do. `p_arr` is indeed a pointer, but it's a *pointer-to-an-array*. This is something basic C tutorials seem reluctant to cover. If you wish to learn more, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays