# How to reallocate/expand 2d array in C?

Tags: c, memory, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm doing [this board game](https://replit.com/@JoanaFerrao/p11#main.c) that lets the players expand the board's columns or rows:

- The board is a 2d array dynamically allocated.
- If the player wanted, the game would add a line (or row).
- To add a row I need to allocate more memory to it right? I keep failing at it, idk what to try anymore..

Here is the code that starts the board in main:

```
  char** tabuleiro = malloc(sizeof(char*) * linhas);
  for(i = 0;i < linhas; i++)
    tabuleiro[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * colunas);
```

Here is the code that starts the aux in the function:

```
  char** insere_jogada(char** tab, jogador j, int* linhas, int*colunas){
  // (...)
  char** aux = tab;
```

Here is the code that would add a row:

```
  *linhas = *linhas + 1;
   aux = realloc(*tab, sizeof(char*)*(*linhas));
   //also tried: tab = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(*linhas));

   if(aux==NULL){
     printf("Error.\n");
     return tab;
   }
```

Here is the code that would add columns:

```
*colunas = *colunas + 1;
for(i = 0;i < *colunas; i++){
  aux[i] = realloc(*tab, sizeof(char*)*(*colunas));
```

Whole function:

```
char** insere_jogada(char** tab, jogador j, int* linhas, int*colunas) {
  int l,c,i;
  char resposta, escolha;
  char** aux = tab;

  pede_espaco(&l,&c); // espaco q o jogador quer jogar
  resposta = check_jogada(tab[l][c], j); //jogada

  if(resposta=='A'){ // se escolher adicionar lin/col
    j.lincol--; //fica sem oportunidade de adicionar mais linhas/colunas

    escolha = pede_lincol(); // escolher entre adicionar linha ou coluna
    if(escolha == 'L'){
      printf("\nLines before %d",*linhas);
      *linhas = *linhas + 1;
       printf("\nLines after %d",*linhas);

      // ----
        aux = realloc(*tab, sizeof(char*)*(*linhas));
        //also tried: tab = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(*linhas));

        if(aux==NULL){
          printf("Error.\n");
          return tab;
        }
      //

    }
    else{
      *colunas = *colunas + 1;
      for(i = 0;i < *colunas; i++){
        aux[i] = realloc(*tab, sizeof(char*)*(*colunas));        
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    tab[l][c] = resposta;
  }

  return aux;
}
```

**PS**: Thank you in advance for your time and patience. This is a new topic for me so forgive me if I'm making an obvious/stupid mistake. :)

Comment: 1) Where do you save `aux` ? 2) How about values already in the board - shall they remain unchanged? 3) How do you create the board to start with? Too little code posted but I think you are doing it wrong

Comment: I will update the question with that code in a sec. thank you :)

Comment: oh yes, i was focused of the first one and it went over my head, fixed it, thank you :)

Comment: First code block: `for(i = 0;i < colunas; i++)` --> `for(i = 0;i < linhas; i++)`

Comment: Is `return aux;` missing?

Comment: and when expanding the rows, you need to allocate for the new row memory too (not just its pointer location).

Comment: `char** aux = tab;` seems unnecessary as `malloc` overwrites

Comment: `aux[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(*colunas));` shouldn't that be a `realloc` so that existing values isn't lost?

Comment: Someone said to change it in a thread here, so I changed. That's kinda my problem, I don't know a lot about this so I try to get help by seeing other people's q&a's but I get so lost and end up messing up my code :/ I'll change it back tho. Thanks!

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, in the whole function I add +1 to the lines/collums variable before. Thank you!

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208929/resizing-2d-arrays-in-c/39209522#39209522

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/67588353/4989451 for inspiration

Comment: Thank you, I will check those!!!

Comment: If you do not need to support rows having different lengths to other rows, it would be much simpler to use a single allocation

Comment: I don't @M.M :)

Comment: @JohnBode That gives me error? https://replit.com/@JoanaFerrao/epa-tabuleiro#main.c